# Install Multiple Package using Sagemaker Life Cycle configuration file

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, configuration, amazon-sagemaker

I wanted to know how I can pre-install Python packages in Sagemaker before spinning it up?

For example, I want to install Tensorfliw, LightFM, and Scikit-optimize

How can i code a Lifecycle Configuration file which will tell sagemaker to install these packages before it spins up and have it ready when I am ready to code.

I know the following resources:

1. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/customize-your-amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instances-with-lifecycle-configurations-and-the-option-to-disable-internet-access/
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi-add-external.html

Answer (score 1):

For Tensorflow, there is an existing Conda environment(*tensorflow_p36*) with TensorFlow preinstalled that you can use. For other packages that aren't present by default, you can use this [Lifecycle Configuration script sample](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/blob/master/scripts/install-pip-package-single-environment/on-start.sh) to install them into the *tensorflow_p36* environment.